# ASP.net Visual Basic The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, iis-7

I am new to VB and ASP.net, learning on a project basis.
I am trying to build a database lookup tool using VB in an ASP.net enviroment.

My website is hosted on IIS 7 in Windows Server 2012 R2. the Database is an Access 2013 DB on the web server

When i navigate to the page with my VB gui it shows correctly, but when i do my lookup i get an error of The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

Stack Trace:

```
[InvalidOperationException: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.]
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbServicesWrapper.GetDataSource(OleDbConnectionString constr, DataSourceWrapper& datasrcWrapper) +1634602
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection) +1651428
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject) +100
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +61
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +953
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +6600667
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +27
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open() +47
   Nekros.cmdLookup_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\xampp\htdocs\nekros\ePSA.aspx.vb:19
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +155
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3804
```

My code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Partial Class Nekros
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim provider As String
    Dim dataFile As String
    Dim connString As String
    Public myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
    Public dr As OleDbDataReader
    Dim prog As String
    Dim start As String
    Private Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
        dataFile = "C:\Shares\share\Projects\Nekros\Database\Nekros.accdb" ' Change it to your Access Database location
        connString = provider & dataFile
        myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
    End Sub

    Private Sub cmdLookup_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdLookup.Click
        myConnection.Open()
        txtFull.Text = ""
        txtMeaning.Text = ""
        txtPOA.Text = ""
        Dim str As String
        str = "SELECT * FROM ePSA WHERE (ePSA = '" & txtePSA.Text & "')"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While dr.Read()
            txtFull.Text = dr("Error").ToString
            txtMeaning.Text = dr("Meaning").ToString
            txtPOA.Text = dr("POA").ToString
        End While
        myConnection.Close()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Please help!

also Please explain as simply as possible as i am still very new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this,Probably enabling 32bit for the apllication pool would solve your problem http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/280/solved-the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine